# How to Find the next value if more than 1 matched Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make the this search to be able to find the next value if more than 1 matched.
[image]

Right now, all it can do it shows the first matched.

Basically, if I press button "NEXT" Then it just go to next matched value.

My logic: I think I must do subtract the total range from the current range but I have trouble with this.

Comment: Can U make an example of it.  I read through your code and I am so confused.

Comment: Which part were you confused at?

Comment: Probably my 2-3 weeks of experience in programming is hard to catch with what you provide.  I need to figure out how to implement the .findnext in .find code. I will try harder

Comment: I can give you the code. It's very simple and hence I wanted you to try it first. :) In the above link, I have given a clear example on how to use `.Findnext`. I would recommend that you give it a try first and if you are still stuck then post the code that you tried and we will take it form there.

Comment: I will try it. I hope I can figure it out by myself.

Comment: @Siddhart Rout, after a few hours swimming through your code, now I have better understanding. I think I almost have it.  I will continue explore it tomorrow.

Comment: New link: Above link will expire soon. This is a permanent link; http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution can be found

[Siddharth Rout's VBA Page](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

[image]

I used a listbox to store the values (Listbox1.AddItem aCell.Address)

Thank you Siddharth Rout